# Check if Pandas column values are not in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of counts within 10 minute time intervals, how would I set count = 0 if the time interval doesn't exist?

**DF1**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'City' : np.random.choice(['PHOENIX','ATLANTA','CHICAGO', 'MIAMI', 'DENVER'], 10000),
                    'Day': np.random.choice(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'], 10000),
                    'Time': np.random.randint(1, 86400, size=10000),
                    'COUNT': np.random.randint(1, 700, size=10000)})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s').dt.round('10min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(df)

      COUNT     City        Day      Time
0       441  PHOENIX   Thursday  10:20:00
1       641  ATLANTA     Monday  14:30:00
2       661  PHOENIX   Saturday  03:50:00
3       570    MIAMI    Tuesday  21:00:00
4       222  CHICAGO     Friday  15:00:00
```

**DF2** - My approach is to create all the 10 minute time slots in a day (6*24 = 144 entries) and then use "not in"

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME_BIN': np.arange(0, 86401, 600), })
df2['TIME_BIN'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['TIME_BIN'], unit='s').dt.round('10min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

     TIME_BIN
0    00:00:00
1    00:10:00
2    00:20:00
3    00:30:00
4    00:40:00
5    00:50:00
6    01:00:00
7    01:10:00
8    01:20:00
```

How do I check if the timeslots in DF2 do not exist in DF1 for each city and day and if so, set count = 0? I basically just need to fill in all the missing time slots in DF1.

**Attempt:**

```
for each_city in df.City.unique():
    for each_day in df.Day.unique():
        df['Time'] = df.apply(lambda row: df2['TIME_BIN'] if row['Time'] not in (df2['TIME_BIN'].tolist()) else None)
```

Comment: You have duplicate in your df1 for Time within each city and day?

Comment: Are you willing to create a histogram from the hours within `df1` based on 10 minutes bins?

Comment: The real data set has no duplicate time slots, the dupes are just a side effect of the randomly generated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'City' : np.random.choice(['PHOENIX','ATLANTA','CHICAGO', 'MIAMI', 'DENVER'], 10000),
                    'Day': np.random.choice(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'], 10000),
                    'Time': np.random.randint(1, 86400, size=10000),
                    'COUNT': np.random.randint(1, 700, size=10000)})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s').dt.round('10min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df = df.drop_duplicates(['City','Day','Time'])
#print(df)
```

---

```
times = (pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(np.arange(0, 86401, 600)), unit='s')
           .dt.round('10min')
           .dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['City'].unique(),
                                  df['Day'].unique(), 
                                  times],names=['City','Day','Time'])
df = (df.set_index(['City','Day','Time'])
        .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())

print (df.head(20))
       City        Day      Time  COUNT
0   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:00:00     66
1   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:10:00    205
2   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:20:00    260
3   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:30:00    127
4   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:40:00    594
5   CHICAGO  Wednesday  00:50:00    683
6   CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:00:00    203
7   CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:10:00      0
8   CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:20:00    372
9   CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:30:00    109
10  CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:40:00     32
11  CHICAGO  Wednesday  01:50:00    184
12  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:00:00    630
13  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:10:00    108
14  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:20:00     35
15  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:30:00    604
16  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:40:00    500
17  CHICAGO  Wednesday  02:50:00    367
18  CHICAGO  Wednesday  03:00:00    118
19  CHICAGO  Wednesday  03:10:00    546
```

Comment: This works, but I'm concerned about the memory overhead for large number of City-Day-Time combinations. It would make sense to convert to categories at some point, even with your MultiIndex solution?

Comment: @jpp - I think aggregate `sum` is not good solution, sorry. OP dont need aggregate data if possible dupes :(

Comment: you mean it should be no problem with categoricals?

Comment: @jpp - But if groupby without aggregate this should be nice, but no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert to categories and use `groupby` to calculate Cartesian product.

In fact, given your data is largely categorical, this is a good idea and would yield memory benefits for large number of Time-City-Day combinations.

```
for col in ['Time', 'City', 'Day']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')

bin_cats = sorted(set(pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0, 86401, 600), unit='s'))\
                                .dt.round('10min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))

df['Time'] = df['Time'].cat.set_categories(bin_cats, ordered=True)

res = df.groupby(['Time', 'City', 'Day'], as_index=False)['COUNT'].sum()
res['COUNT'] = res['COUNT'].fillna(0).astype(int)

#           Time     City        Day  COUNT
# 0     00:00:00  ATLANTA     Friday    521
# 1     00:00:00  ATLANTA     Monday    767
# 2     00:00:00  ATLANTA   Saturday    474
# 3     00:00:00  ATLANTA     Sunday   1126
# 4     00:00:00  ATLANTA   Thursday    157
# 5     00:00:00  ATLANTA    Tuesday    720
# 6     00:00:00  ATLANTA  Wednesday      0
# 7     00:00:00  CHICAGO     Friday   1114
# 8     00:00:00  CHICAGO     Monday    813
# 9     00:00:00  CHICAGO   Saturday    137
# 10    00:00:00  CHICAGO     Sunday    134
# 11    00:00:00  CHICAGO   Thursday      0
# 12    00:00:00  CHICAGO    Tuesday    168
# ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try following

```
df.groupby(['City','Day']).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Time').reindex(df2.TIME_BIN.unique()).fillna({'COUNT':0}).ffill())
```